# How to pass special characters and digits in cucumber data table

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

In cucumber feature file, am trying to send username and password. password is a mix of specialcharacters, digits and alphabet like

> "Password#2"

. I tried escaping with slashes like

> "Password/#2", "Password\#2" , "Password/#/2"

and double slashes as well but not successful. How can we pass such special characters in cucumber feature file.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You should be able to pass special characters with no problem. Can you include the full step and step definition?

Comment: My guess would be this is a problem with something else in your code, like your matching or parsing.